# zopim live chat issue on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, zopim

Hello everyone how are you.
Recently i installed WordPress on my website. And also install the zopim live chat plugins but it's working good on home page. but not working good on the sub page.

My home page URL is : http://buyvotes.net/

One subpage URL is : http://buyvotes.net/buy-facebook-votes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theme is custom theme then make sure you already added wp_head(); on your header section and wp_footer(); on the footer section.

If all ok it should be work good.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, let me check it.